# Where is the "XYZ door" in Fez?

Tags: fez

Where is the "XYZ door" in Fez?

[image]

I saw it once and I can't find it now.

Comment: I have never seen this door in game. Any idea of WHERE you might have seen it? this pattern IS on some of the posters and stuff (boiler room).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, **this is an unused sprite**. The doors that would have those letters are most often letter-less. If anything they have two overlapping squares:

[image: overlapping squares]